# Принадлежит ли страница пользователю

Tags: php

Адрес страницы пользователя имеет вид `profile?id=1` подскажите, как можно узнать, что пользователь на своей странице (что id страницы такой же как и id пользователя) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас в сессии или в куках лежит логин. По логину узнаем ID. Если этот ID совпадает с ID из метода GET, тогда производится дейтсвие...